# Clarification on why my post was closed and deleted

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I had [a post](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/in-which-indiana-jones-movie-do-the-planets-align)  (2k+ only) that was deleted, but there is no moderator comment indicating why.

The only thing wrong with it is apparently I'm confusing some movies I had watched. I had thought it was Indiana Jones, but it looks like I was mistaken. I don't see why this would have been deleted though.

As an [SE moderator myself](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/users/65/corsika), I'm pretty familiar with the SE model, and am having trouble rationalizing why it's been closed, much less deleted.

Can a moderator give input behind the thought process?

Answer (score 4):

We have a process where we go through and close id questions that don't have an accepted answer, and after a question has been closed for over a month we go through and delete them.

This particular question had an answer upvoted enough that, now, I would have reopened it instead of deleting it.

I have undeleted and reopened the question.  If the Lara Croft answer is indeed the correct one, please accept it.

Comment: I had forgotten about the question entirely. I'm going to have to take a stab at watching a the Lara Croft movie, as well as the Macguyver movie, to see if they have the scene I recall. Thankfully, the number of movies in which planetary alignments are observed are fairly low. :)

Comment: Although I have to follow up and ask (this may warrant an additional question if others want to chime in) why delete unanswered questions? That seems highly contrary to the SE philosophy, as it's the questions without answers that are in highest need of (and therefore more likely to attract) the attention of an expert. It would seem anything that would cause a question to be closed should be entirely unrelated to the duration of the question's unanswered period.

Comment: @corsiKa - we don't delete unanswered questions per se, just unanswered identification questions.  These tend to be very localized questions, generally only useful to one person - if they don't seem to be 'interacting' with the question in any way (commenting on wrong answers, providing more detail, accepting correct answers etc) then the question is considered dead.  You are the only arbiter of whether the answers given are correct, and the question is only meaningful to you really - if you forgot about it, its not actually that useful to others.

Comment: @iandotkelly I don't understand - if the question is eligible for closing and deletion after a particular amount of time, why isn't it eligible from the moment it's created? It seems askew to the SE model to have a question whose eligibility changes over time with no changes other *than* elapsed time.

Comment: @corsiKa to my knowledge there are only two sites that allow identification questions, Movies and Scifi.  Both sites have different rules as to how we handle these.  Since this type of question encourages a lot of drive-by questions and have a high rate of non-acceptance or unanswerability, we decided to keep them on a relatively short leash to keep them from junking up the site too much.  If you want you could start a discussion about the ID cleanup policies to clean up any confusion.